# Google Play console : why "daily install events" much higher than daily "user installs"?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

There is a new metrics in Google Play console named "install events" (daily install events). I just compared these metrics to the classical "user installs" (I have the french version of the console by I think that the translation in English on the console is daily "Installs per user").

I don't understand why the "install events" are rough, in my case, 50% higher than the daily "Installs per user".

Is it because of the installs after the users changed their device? Installs on multiple devices? (tablet and phone) Else?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Installs by User is "Unique users who installed the app on one or more of their devices for the first time."

Install Events is "How many times the app has been installed on a device, including devices that previously uninstalled your app and are installing it again."

The first statistic is user oriented and first time only. The second is device oriented and every install counts. Upgrades are not installs.

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Comment: For my app, install events is 3x higher than installs by user. Uninstall events is 2x higher than uninstalls by user. This means on average users of my app install it three times and uninstall it once. The only thing I can think of is that a user might uninstall and install my app several times over a period of years, sometimes just because they got a new phone; this would count as 1 install by user, but several install events.